# Rotation that forms a non-circular shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, perspective

I was looking at this interesting album art

[image]

How do I get to this concentric effect on a shape that is non-circular? I tried to draw the triangle and his center point, and then adjust the anchor points to the external shape and to the center point. I am kind of getting there, but the process is tedious and the result doesn't look so appealing:

[image]

Is there some feature, like transform and distort, that would help me achieve a better result?

Thanks!

Comment: You can cut the lines after they ahve been created

Comment: Make the spokes in a radius and clip them into a triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the most efficient if you have a lot of points to transform but you could start with a dashed stroke on your outer object, expand the stroke, select all the inner points then use the Scale Tool to scale those inner points:

[image]

Which gives us this:

[image]

Comment: Awesome. I wonder how you guys come up with these solutions, that after they have been shown look quite obvious, but before they are not immediate to me. Thank you!

Comment: @StefanoPesce We spend quite many hours of our waking time pondering about geometrical issues.